# android CalledFromWrongThreadException

Tags: java, android, exception

Hi I am making a chat application however when I try to update the view with the received string I get an `CalledFromWrongThreadException`, however it worked earlier, and my understanding of the handler is that it is created exactly for calls from another thread.

```
public class ChatActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ServerSocket serverSocket;
Thread listenThread;
Thread sendThread;
Socket socket = null;
String strIP = "";
volatile String error;
final static int port = 6000;
TextView chatView;
TextView errorView;
volatile static String rcv = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }


    if (socket == null) {
        try {
            this.listenThread = new Thread(new Listener());
            this.listenThread.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chat, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.action_connectIP) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConnectActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == 1) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (data.hasExtra("IP"))
                strIP = data.getExtras().getString("IP");
            Toast.makeText(this, strIP, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // luk for at forhindre flere i at forbinde
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                error = e.toString();
                Message message = new Message();
                message.what = -1;
                UpdateHandler.sendMessage(message);             }

        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (listenThread != null)
        if (listenThread.isAlive())
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                error = e.toString();
                Message message = new Message();
                message.what = -1;
                UpdateHandler.sendMessage(message);

            }
    listenThread.interrupt();

    if (sendThread != null)
        if (sendThread.isAlive())
            sendThread.interrupt();

}

Handler UpdateHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        this.obtainMessage();
        switch (msg.toString()) {
        case "0":
            // TODO: afbryd forbindelsen
            break;
        case "-1":
            insertError();
            break;

        default:
            InsertChat();
        }
    }
};

void ThreadHandler() {

}

void InsertChat() {
    if(chatView != null)
        chatView.setText(rcv);
    else
    {
        chatView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewChat);
        chatView.setText(rcv);
    }
}

void insertError()
{
    errorView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewFejl);
    errorView.setText(error);

}

public void SendChat(View view) {
    // gør det hele asynkront og send beskeder i en tråd for sig.
    if(sendThread == null)
        sendThread = new Thread(new SendMessage());
    if (!sendThread.isAlive()) {
        this.sendThread = new Thread(new SendMessage());
        this.sendThread.start();
    }

}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

class Listener implements Runnable {
    boolean shouldRun = true;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        // Looper.loop();

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        if (socket == null) {
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


            Message message = new Message();
            rcv = "debug1";
            UpdateHandler.sendMessage(message);
            try {
                    if(strIP != "")
                        socket = new Socket(strIP, port);

                    else if (socket == null)
                        socket = serverSocket.accept();


                    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), socket.getInetAddress().toString()+ " er forbundet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && shouldRun) {

                        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));


                        rcv = reader.readLine();
                        if(rcv == null) //er forbindelsen forsvundet?
                            shouldRun = false;
                        else
                        {
                            message.what = 0;
                            UpdateHandler.dispatchMessage(Message.obtain());
                        }

                    }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                error = e.toString();
                message.what = -1;
                UpdateHandler.dispatchMessage(message);
                if(e != null)
                    e.printStackTrace();

            }

        try {
            if (reader != null)
            {   
                reader.close();
                    socket.close();
                    socket = null;
                    serverSocket.close();

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

            error = e.toString();
            message.what = -1;
            UpdateHandler.dispatchMessage(message);
            if(e != null)
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "lukker", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}

class SendMessage implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        try {
            EditText textBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtChat);
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())));
            writer.println(textBox.getText().toString());
            writer.flush(); //send før bufferen er fuld

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fejl", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}

}
```

I can't figure out how else to update the UI since you can't run sockets on the UI thread.

Comment: updating ui from a non ui thread? Handler is associated with the thread in which it is created.

Comment: the Handler is created on the main thread or UI thread, however it is when it's called from another thread the problem arises

Comment: Apparantly it is because UpdateHandler.dispatchMessage(), cause when i use sendMessage and leave out the message.what i atleast get another error. Now the problem is that The specified message queue synchronization  barrier token has not been posted or has already been removed. That should be fixed with the dispatchMessage but that gives another error.